# Import Order from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, importexport

I need to import orders from m1 to m2 and available orders in m1 are a minimum of **2 lakh** on the m1 website. So I thought we were going with SQL and importing orders using SQL.

if anyone has created an order from SQL then please Post here.

So I need to understand if this is a better way or if we can go with another way.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To migrate the order data from **Magento 1 to Magento2** you can use the **Data Migration tool** which will import the orders from **Magento 1 to Magento2**. Below is the official link to setup the data migration tool.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/tools/data-migration/basics/install.html?lang=en#

**Another way (Not recommended)** you can export the order from the Magento 1 and Update the file  according to Magento 2 standards in this way you can import the order data but that was not recommended and you can get issues as well.

Comment: you are right but we have more than 2 lakh orders So I thought without SQL it's not possible